# How to remove double quotes from keys in RDD and split JSON into two lines?

Tags: regex, scala, dictionary, apache-spark, rdd

I need to modify the data to give input to CEP system, my current data looks like below

```
val rdd = {"var":"system-ready","value":0.0,"objectID":"2018","partnumber":2,"t":"2017-08-25 11:27:39.000"}
```

I need output like

```
t = "2017-08-25 11:27:39.000
Check = { var = "system-ready",value = 0.0, objectID = "2018", partnumber = 2 }
```

I have to write RDD map operations to achieve this if anybody suggests better option welcome. colcount is the number of columns.

```
rdd.map(x => x.split("\":").mkString("\" ="))                                                        
            .map((f => (f.dropRight(1).split(",").last.toString, f.drop(1).split(",").toSeq.take(colCount-1).toString))) 
            .map(f => (f._1, f._2.replace("WrappedArray(", "Check = {")))                                   
            .map(f => (f._1.drop(0).replace("\"t\"", "t"), f._2.dropRight(1).replace("(", "{")))              /
            .map(f => f.toString().split(",C").mkString("\nC").replace(")", "}").drop(0).replace("(", ""))    //  replacing , with \n, droping (
            .map(f => f.replace("\" =\"", "=\"").replace("\", \"", "\",").replace("\" =", "=").replace(", \"", ",").replace("{\"", "{"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala's JSON parser seems to be a good choice for this problem:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json

rdd.map( x => {
                JSON.parseFull(x).get.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
        })
```

This will result in an `RDD[Map[String, String]]`. You can then access the `t` field from the JSON, for example, using:

```
.map(dict => "t = "+dict("t"))
```

Comment: thanks Arun, I tried parsefull earlier but not taken to Map. small change to your code worked for me.
`map( x => { JSON.parseFull(x).get.asInstanceOf[ scala.collection.immutable.Map[String, String]]})`

Comment: @anandbabu  Feel free to accept the answer if you found it useful so that the community sees this question as solved. Thanks!